# Find facebook profile id by url

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get the facebook id by the facebook url name.
Example:
http://findmyfacebookid.com/
This sites does what I want to.
1-2 months ago I could go to
graph.facebook.com/Facebook
And I would get a JSON with the ID of the page, now is not working anymore, because I need to use OAUTH.

Is there a way to get the facebook id by the url without any oauth things?

Comment: If this is a one-time thing, you can do it f.e. using the Graph API Explorer. This will only works for pages though – users can not be looked up by their username any more with API v2, because Facebook removed that field.

Answer (score 1):

Its So Simple..
if you look at the source code of the any of the facebook profile and then search for "profile_id" and its value using any of pattern matching techniques in jquery,php or any language you can easily get the profile id without oauth techniques.

Comment: You might need to be logged in for this to work, but I've verified that it does, whereas http://findmyfacebookid.com/ didn't work to find the FB id of a friend.

Comment: no i have checked, you don't have to be logged in for the above method. it works even if you are logged out

Answer (score 1):

Using old scraping style still works until FB close all public data and force everyone to using 100% api with permission token.

2 basic things needed:

1. Get source code of profile from username url.
2. Extract fb id. Its located scatted around html and the very nearest is at meta tag.

Done!!